# Populating multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

The code below came as an included file with a beginner puzzle app tutorial I'm working through. The code works, however now that I've completed the tutorial, I'm trying to read through the files that came preloaded which were not explained.

I'm really tripped up over the "spacecount" variable, and what exactly it's doing. Can anyone comment each line in plain english, so that I can better understand how exactly the code below is populating the rowCount array. Thank you so much.

```
var totalRows = puzzle.length;
var totalCols = puzzle[0].length;

/* Loop through the rows to create the rowCount array 
containing the totals for each row in the puzzle */

var rowCount = [];
for (var i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
  rowCount[i]="";
  spaceCount = 0;

  for (var j = 0; j < totalCols; j++) {
     if (puzzle[i][j] == "#") {
        spaceCount++; 

       if (j == totalCols-1) rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
       } else {
          if (spaceCount > 0) {
           rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
           spaceCount = 0;
        } 
      }    
    }
```

Comment: @Blender, any help you can give would be appreciated.

Comment: See my answer. It should make things a bit clearer. Also, if you find that an answer answers your question, check the green checkmark (you seem to have forgotten to do this for previous questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly more legible version:

```
var totalRows = puzzle.length;
var totalCols = puzzle[0].length;

/* Loop through the rows to create the rowCount array 
containing the totals for each row in the puzzle */

var rowCount = [];

for (var i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
    rowCount[i] = "";
    spaceCount = 0;

    for (var j = 0; j < totalCols; j++) {
        if (puzzle[i][j] == "#") {
            spaceCount++;

            if (j == totalCols - 1) {
                rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
        } else if (spaceCount > 0) {
            rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            spaceCount = 0;
        }
    }
}​
```

The confusing parts are probably the `if` blocks in the middle.

```
if (puzzle[i][j] == "#") {     // If a puzzle piece is `#` (a space?)
    spaceCount++;              // Increment the spaceCount by 1.

    if (j == totalCols - 1) {  // Only if we are on the last column, add the text
                               // to the row.
        rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
} else if (spaceCount > 0) {   // If the current piece isn't a `#` but 
                               // spaces have already been counted,
                               // add them to the row's text and reset `spaceCount`
    rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    spaceCount = 0;
}​
```

From what I can tell, this code counts the number of consecutive pound signs and appends this text to each row.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm confused about the value of rowCount[i] after the line rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" How is the value of spaceCount (which is now 1), being added to rowCount[i]?

Comment: You're using the `+=` operator. `a += 1` is equivalent to `a = a + 1`.

Comment: I also do not see how the else if statement (spaceCount > 0) will ever be true since we set the value of spaceCounter to 0 and only increment it as a part of the if statement?

Comment: It will only be true if the first `if` statement runs, which only happens if there are `#` symbols in the row.

Comment: Yes, I have seen how the += operator works, but what is the end result of adding "1" to rowCount. I am unsure how rowCount and spaceCount can be added together.

Comment: You're adding `spaceCount` to `rowCount[i]`, not `rowCount`. `rowCount[i]` is a string. `rowCount` is an array (from what I can tell).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18018/discussion-between-amk-and-blender)